# How do I install Apache spark and get it up and running with Kafka?

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-kafka

I am quite new to Hadoop and Apache Spark. I am a beginner trying my hands on it. Now, I am trying to try my hands on Apache Spark. In order to do that, I am assuming I have to install a software named Apache Spark on my machine.

I tried to create a local machine using VM but I am lost at this point. Is there any resource to help me configure and install Spark and Kafka in the same machine  ?

Answer (score 0):

You are in luck, Chris Fregley (from the IBM Spark TC) has a project which has docker images for all of these things working together (you can see it at https://github.com/fluxcapacitor/pipeline/wiki ). For a "real" production deployment, you might want to look at deploying Spark on YARN or something similar - its deployment options are explained at http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/cluster-overview.html and integrating it with Kafka is covered in the special Kafka integration guide http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-integration.html . Welcome to the wonderful of Spark I hope these help you get started :)